# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Nesting Lists ASP.NET MVC LINQ Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

As the title says, im getting that error when trying to get the value out of an user object to be displayed. Im using Entity Framework Code-First, so all the Models are generated, im trying to combine multiple tables with eachother. "Displaying all users with their project data and flextime" (Now flextime is just a decimal)

Model:

```
    public class ListModel
{
    public List<StaffModel> StaffModelList { get; set; } 
}

    public class StaffModel
{
    public FlexModel Flex { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProjectName { get; set; }
}

    public class FlexModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public decimal FlexTime { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Aviato.ViewModel.ListModel 

<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model.StaffModelList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.UserId</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.FlexTime</td>
            <td>@item.ProjectName</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.SocialSecurityNumber</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.FirstName</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.LastName</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.Address1</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.ZipCode</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.City</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.PhoneNumber1</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.EmploymentStartDate</td>
            <td>@item.Flex.User.Password</td>

            @foreach (var project in item.ProjectName)
            {
                <td>@project</td>
            }

            @Html.ActionLink("Redigera", "Edit", new { id = item.Flex.User.UserId })
            @Html.ActionLink("Ta bort", "Delete", new { id = item.Flex.User.UserId })
        </tr>
       }
</table>
```

Controller:

```
private readonly AviatoModel _db = new AviatoModel(); //Database

public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var projects = _db.Projects.ToList();
        var users = _db.Users.ToList();
        var model = new ListModel();

        model.StaffModelList = new List<StaffModel>();

        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            var flexModel = new StaffModel();
            flexModel.Flex.User = u; //This is where the Error occurs.
            flexModel.Flex.FlexTime = GetFlex.Flex(u.UserId);
            model.StaffModelList.Add(flexModel);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: About that exception: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/121309 A hint: what is the value of `flexModel.Flex` at that error line and why?

Comment: pretty much your object is null that you're sending from your controller

Comment: Yeah well, that doesnt help me much. Why is it null?

Comment: You're not assigning anything to `flexModel.Flex`, so `flexModel.Flex.User` doesn't exist

Comment: flexModel Does not have a property or field which having the name Flex

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan - he's not assigning to a `FlexModel` type, he's assigning to a `StaffModel` type _called_ flexModel, which does have a `Flex` property - confusing, i know!

Comment: @markpsmith Indeed, took me a moment to figure that one out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Flex` property of `StaffModel` is never instantiated so when you try to access a method on it, you get the `NullReferenceException`. Add a constructor to your class like this to create it as an empty object:

```
public class StaffModel
{
    public StaffModel()
    {
        Flex = new FlexModel();
    }

    //snip
}
```